# HTML Validation Error head and body tags

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.0

I have a problem when validating my html. It says stray head tag and some problems with my body tag. Can someone check that out and find my problem? I can't find the problem... My URL is www.magmaar.de

Comment: Please don't ask for on site debugging on Stack Exchange. Instead describe the problems in detail and include the relevant source code, so that the question and answers will still be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's because you've got a `<div>` tag inside your `<head>` tag:

From line 79 to the end of the `<head>` tag:

```
<div id="auorg-bg">
<a href="https://www.ausgezeichnet.org" target="_blank" title="Unabh&auml;ngige Bewertungen, Kundenbewertungen und G&uuml;tesiegel von Ausgezeichnet.org" class="auorg-br">
<span style="font-size:8px;font-weight:normal;text-transform:uppercase;">Ausgezeichnet.org</span></a>
</div>
```